# What is the different between online and offline generation in FaceNet

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In paper 
[FaceNet: A Unified Embedding for Face Recognition and Clustering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832), what are the online and offline generation? And what is the different between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically online means you only use the current batch (~ doing things on the fly). The paper follows this is usage. Quoting them:

> There are two obvious choices that avoid this issue: 
> • Generate
>   triplets offline every n steps, using the most recent network
>   checkpoint and computing the argmin and argmax on a subset of the
>   data. 
> • Generate triplets online. This can be done by selecting the
>   hard positive/negative exemplars from within a mini-batch.

Comment: And what is the offline learning?